# How do I make <divs> in Twitter bootstrap appear in a Masonry Format with Jquery Masonry and Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I am trying to get each  on the following page:

http://snowbird.camorada.com/test.php

to look in a masonry format like the following:

http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html

Here is the div that I want to appear in masonry format:

```
      <div class="tiled">
          <div class="newz_caption" style="background: #FFFFFF;">
               //content
          </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the code that I am using to select the , (Sorry for the comments)

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('#container').masonry({
        // options  
        itemSelector : '.tiled',
        isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions

      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: So, what actually is the problem/question? You have a bare-bones jsfiddle or online sandbox with some code (that fails or partially works) you've tried - for us to look at?

Comment: The links that I sent you have the <div> , unfortunatley it would be difficult to reproduce the code via a js fiddle because it requires modernizr, twitter bootstrap, and jquery masonry.

What I am trying to do is make the <div class="tiled"> appear in masonry format like this example:
http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html

Does that make sense? Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you use Masonry's big brother Isotope (has modernizr implemented already, has Masonry layout mode)? On jsfiddle, you can simply link to resources like jQuery, Masonry, Isotope, whatever - as long as some CDN hosts it or you can link the latest version from github. Then, it's easy to build an interactively modifiable sandbox there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As always, Google is your best [friend](http://mpezzi.github.com/bootstrap_isotope/), [mate](http://pknopf.com/blog/jquery-isotope-with-responsive-twitter-bootstrap) or [sugardaddy](http://www.maurizioconventi.com/2012/06/19/responsive-example-integrating-twitter-bootstrap-and-jquery-masonry/).

Comment: I did already find Maurizo's post, and I have googled this. Maurizo's post is a little confusing to me. Thanks

Comment: When you look into Maurizio's implementation, it's all just 57 lines of very straightforward code; the plugins doing the rest of the work for you. What's confusing about it?

Comment: With Maurizio's code I was able to re-implement it on my server, but it is only for images using Masonry, not necessarily the example that I liked to above.
I am trying ti implement Maurizio's code without images, but the <div class="box"> is not appearing in masonry. 

Here's the link to the site where i'm having the issues:

http://snowbird.camorada.com/BootstrapMasonry/yellow.php

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly? 1. Shall the image divs (.box class) and the text divs (.box class as well) be mixed with each other? Shall the text divs (.box class) NOT appear in a single column underneath the images? Regarding 1. They would have to be shuffled, or filtered or sorted (Isotope does this). Regarding 2. Your text divs have the .box class - but NOT the .masonry-brick class (like the image divs) if you check them with Google Chrome's devtools. You also see there that they are NOT actually inside your #content div, but simply in the regular DOM flow underneath it...

Comment: Best is maybe to just use very few image divs and text divs and see, where the apparently necessary .masonry-brick class comes from, so the text divs are not outside of your Masonry #content div...

Comment: Thanks systembolaget. I did figure out that I just did not have it within the right div as you mentioned. Thanks! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Best answer that i've seen until now!

Comment: Also a good thing to do is to not put only links in your answer. 2 out of 3 links are broken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using bootstrap with masonry is the columns are different sizes dependent on your screen size.

you may try this solution : 
http://www.deanclatworthy.com/2012/09/responsive-twitter-bootstrap-masonry/